# Adding new indexes to an array inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So, I have this:

```
$abc = array('a','b','c');
foreach ($abc as $k => &$a) {
    echo $a;
    if ($k == 1)
        $abc[] = 'd';
}
```

Work's as expected, iterating through the foreach 4 times and giving me:

```
abcd
```

But now, when I have this:

```
$myvar = $this->someModel->return_an_array_as_result(); // returns array([0] => array('a' => 'b'))

foreach ($myvar as $myvar_key => &$mv){
    $myvar[] = array('e' => 'f');
    var_dump($myvar);
    if ($myvar_key == 5) die;
}
```

The foreach only runs once.

Any thoughts on how foreach works when resetting the internal pointer?

Comment: yes it would run once ... you said `$myvar` returns `array([0] => array('a' => 'b'))`

Comment: Yep, but take a closer look at the second code: `$myvar[]`

Comment: See updated answer ... It  you should use `ArrayObject` Insted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your point,  you can use `ArrayObject` which would allow append to array while you are still loop through the array

```
$myvar = new ArrayObject(array('a' => 'b'));
$x = 0;
foreach ( $myvar as $myvar_key => $mv ) {
    $myvar->append(array('e' => 'f'));
    if (($x >= 4))
        break;
    $x ++;
}
var_dump($myvar);
```

Output

```
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'a' => string 'b' (length=1)
    array
      'e' => string 'f' (length=1)
    array
      'e' => string 'f' (length=1)
    array
      'e' => string 'f' (length=1)
    array
      'e' => string 'f' (length=1)
    array
      'e' => string 'f' (length=1)
```

Comment: Isn't perfect, because now I have an object instead of an array to work with. But still a very good solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: @jlcd `(array) $myvar` would convert it to array .. simple as that

Comment: Indeed, `ArrayObject` implements a dynamic Enumerable interface that's cognizant of changes in between `next` calls. +1 for another approach.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `foreach` is actually working on a *copy* of the array. If you're planning on modifying the array while you're iterating over it, use a traditional `for` loop.

For more information, see the PHP docs on [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Also, if you're looking to modify elements while iterating, you can [`&$reference`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) them (more information about this also found in the `foreach` docs).

Comment: You're not relying on a condition to exit (the condition has already been met in the second iteration, the addendum was added, and the loop exited). The second example doesn't have 5 elements (nor will it for the duration of the loop) as when `foreach` took a snap-shot it only had 3 elements. And because it's a copy and not a reference, the `foreach` will long exit before it realizes there are 5 elements.

Comment: But `$myvar[]` should add infinite new indexes to the `$myvar` array, therefore should, at some point, have 5 elements. What's happening is  the foreach iterating one time through the so called "snapshot" and ignoring the new position. I can't find the difference between the first to the second example.

Comment: @jlcd: When you use `foreach` it's pre-deturmined how many iterations will be executed when the loop _begins_ (no matter how many modifications you make within the loop itself--add, remove, edit). Because of the way you intialized `$abc` in the first array a key value of `[1]` existed when the `foreach` began so `$k==1` was inevitably hit. However, in your second example `$myvar_key == 5` didn't exist at execution and, no matter how many times you change the array, that condition won't be hit because key 5 didn't exist when it started.

Comment: the only reason I used `$k == 1` is to avoid an infinite loop. You *can* change the array size by adding new indexes to it, therefore making the foreach iterate more times than at first. Please try to run the first example without the `if` inside the foreach and you should get an infinite loop.

Comment: @jlcd: [Not true](http://ideone.com/mqhYI), which is the message I'm trying to convey. It's iterating over a _copy_, not the array itself. However, if you did `for ($k = 0; $k < count($ary); $k++){ $ary[] = chr(100+$k); }` you _will_ get an infinite loop because it's working on the reference and not a copy.